# Python server uses socket and threading modules, threads aren't garbage collected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, python-multithreading, python-sockets

The issue can be simulated on Windows with Python 3.11.2. Interestingly enough, it doesn't seem to happen on macOS. I haven't tested Linux yet.

Is something missing from threading on Windows? I added in the "del" and manual garbage collection because the memory use just keeps growing. If you take them out, it just grows even faster. I'm re-joining and garbage collecting threads. The threads are returning at the end of the code. I've tried it using import sys, and sys.exit() as well. The behavior is generally the same.

This is meant to be a long running script that collects data from multiple clients. The code below is the complete code necessary to replicate the memory issue on Windows.

threading_mem_leak.py:

```
import threading
import socket
import gc

def main():
    ServerSideSocket = socket.socket()
    host = ''
    port = 8083
    try:
        ServerSideSocket.bind((host, port))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(str(e))
    
    #print('Socket is listening')
    ServerSideSocket.listen(5)

    while True:
        Client, address = ServerSideSocket.accept()
        thread_unique_name = address[0] + ":" + str(address[1])
        thread = threading.Thread(group=None,target=multi_threaded_client, 
                                  name=thread_unique_name,
                                  args=(Client,), kwargs={}, daemon=None)
        #print("Connected to: " + address[0] + " : " + str(address[1]))
        thread.start()
        print("The thread for connection " + thread.getName() + " has started")
        #print(threading.enumerate())
        thread.join()
        gc.collect()


def multi_threaded_client(connection):
    data = connection.recv(2048)
    data.decode('utf-8')
    if not data:
        connection.close()
        del data
        del connection
        gc.collect()
        return
    connection.close()
    data1 = str(data)

    msglist = data1.split('|')

    var1 = msglist[0][2:]
    var2 = var1[:-3]
    var3 = msglist[1]

    # code that does stuff here #

    del connection
    del msglist
    del data
    del data1
    del var1
    del var2
    del var3

    gc.collect()
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

client.py:

```
import socket

while True:
    ClientSideSocket = socket.socket()
    try:
        s = socket.socket()
    except socket.error as err:
        print("Socket Error")
    bytes2send = str.encode("var1|var2|var3")
    try:
        s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8083))
    except socket.error as err:
        print("couldn't connect")
    try:
        s.sendall(bytes2send)
    except:
        print("couldn't send data")
    s.close()
```

I've tried running this on macOS and Linux (the memory issue isn't replicated there), I've tried garbage collecting in different places and using different generations, manually deleting objects using del, and I've used both the _thread module and the threading module. The memory still grows uncontrollably over time.

Comment: Can't reproduce, tried with python-3.11.2-embed-amd64.zip. Even removed all `gc` and `del` stuff, and added a `print('\n'.join(str(s) for s in tracemalloc.take_snapshot().statistics('filename')))` (checked with `'lineno'` too, just to make sure it really tracks allocations from the thread). What are you looking at exactly? Graphs and numbers in Process Explorer or Resource Monitor also seem fine.

Comment: Windows 11, Intel CPU, standard cpython 64 bit, launch the first file first, then separately the second file. Memory kept growing. Started around 7-8 MB and kept growing. Running on a Windows server and receiving messages overnight from multiple clients memory growth was over 1.5 GB. Per Windows Task Manager’s details tab. Did you change anything in either file?